# Am I supposed to be able to detect multi-finger taps this way?

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

This is the touchesBegan method for a view that has multiple touches enabled.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touches count] > 1)
        NSLog(@"multi touches: %d fingers", [touches count]);

    NSUInteger numTaps = [touch tapCount];

    if (numTaps == 1) {
        NSLog(@"single tap");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"multi tap: %d", numTaps);
    }
}
```

I never seem to log a multi-touch.  Just single and double taps.  Am I wrong to have assumed it was as easy as getting the count for touches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried three different ways and only one can return two to five finger taps.  The winning mechanism is NSSet *touch = [event allTouches];

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    // the next line will not ever return a multiple tap
    if ([touches count] > 1)
        NSLog(@"multi-touches %d", [touches count]);
    // the next line will return up to 5 (verified) simultaneous taps (maybe more)
        NSSet *touch2 = [event allTouches];
    if ([touch2 count] > 1)
        NSLog(@"multi-touches2 %d", [touch2 count]);
    // the next line only returns 1 tap
        NSSet *touch3 = [event touchesForView:self];
    if ([touch3 count] > 1)
        NSLog(@"multi-touches2 %d", [touch3 count]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: [touches count] does not give the number of touches, but [[event allTouches] count] does.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `multipleTouchEnabled` property to `YES` on the view to let it send you multiple number of `UITouch` objects.

Beside that, only `UITouch` objects that changed are passed. If you touch some location and don't move your finger and after that, touch another location, only the new touch object will be passed. You should query `UIEvent` object for all active touches in the view:

```
[event touchesForView:self]
```

Comment: I just added the fact that the mutliple touch property is enabled (and it doesn't work).

Comment: That doesn't work.  This does:  NSSet *touch = [event allTouches];

Comment: mahboudz: It should work if both touches start in the specific view. Of course, by `self`, I mean the view instance.

Answer (score -1):

Winning mechanism?   With errors and vars that aren't even being used?

incompatible Objective-C types 'struct AViewController *', expected 'struct UIView *' when passing argument 1 of 'touchesForView:' from distinct Objective-C type

AViewController.m:64:unused variable 'touch'

Comment: First off, the winning mechanism is just "NSSet *touch = [event allTouches];"

Comment: Secondly, you're the one who's defining self.  If your self isn't a UIView, then don't blame someone else.

Comment: Lastly, try to understand the answer instead of just copying it and expecting it to be perfectly suited to your needs.  Do you really think that this method below, with "touch" unused is production code?